# Location Services taking a lot of time to get a coarse location from FusedLocationApi

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-api-client, google-location-services

I have this app where I need to get a single **coarse** location (I'm only requesting for `android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`) as quickly as possible before starting showing anything (besides a splash screen) to the user.

For some reason(s) my code is not working in some use cases where it needs to request for a location update (if it can't find a last know location).

- If Location Services were disabled recently and I enable them back and then launch my app, it might take a lot of time (or not) to get a location fix and it might never happen. In this situation, I usually have to disable the Location Services and enable them back with the quick switch button from the notifications dropdown with the app in the foreground. And it's not immediate either, it takes a few seconds.
- Another similar case is where the Location Services are disabled, I open the app and can't get a fix. I open the device settings (placing the app in the background), re-enable Location Services and bring the app back to the foreground. It takes a lot of time to get a location fix sometimes.

Honestly, it's complicated for me to describe the use cases where it usually takes a lot of time to get a fix on location. I've tried many things, constantly disabling/enabling Location services, with the app opened/closed, on the foreground/background. Many things, it just doesn't work consistently.

And given the nature of my app, I really need to get a single location fix as quickly as possible. And since I don't need a precise location (a really rough estimate is fine), I don't understand why it takes so long...

Sorry for the long post, here's my current code:

```
// BaseActivityLifecycleCallbacks extends Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks with default blank methods

public class MyLocation extends BaseActivityLifecycleCallbacks implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    private static final int LOCATION_REQUEST_INTERVAL = 1000; // 1 second
    private static final int LOCATION_REQUEST_FASTEST_INTERVAL = 250; // 250 milliseconds

    private static final int LOCATION_REQUEST_UPDATE_TIMEOUT = 15000; // 15 seconds

    private final Handler mMainHandler;
    private final Runnable mExpiredRunnable;
    private final GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private final LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    private LocationCallback mLocationCallback;

    @DebugLog
    public MyLocation(Context context) {
        mMainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        mExpiredRunnable = new Runnable() {

            @DebugLog
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handleNewOrEmptyLocation(null);
            }

        };

        MyApplication.getInstance().registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();

        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(LOCATION_REQUEST_INTERVAL)
            .setFastestInterval(LOCATION_REQUEST_FASTEST_INTERVAL);
    }

    public void requestFusedLocation(@NonNull LocationCallback callback) {
        mLocationCallback = callback;

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @DebugLog
    @Override
    public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
        super.onActivityResumed(activity);

        if (activity instanceof MainActivity) {
            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && !mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting() && mLocationCallback != null) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }

    @DebugLog
    @Override
    public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
        super.onActivityPaused(activity);

        if (activity instanceof MainActivity) {
            if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                mMainHandler.removeCallbacks(mExpiredRunnable);

                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);

                mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }

    @DebugLog
    @Override
    // I'm handling permission request some place else...
    @SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Location lastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

        if (lastLocation != null) {
            handleNewOrEmptyLocation(lastLocation);
            return;
        }

        // I've disabled this for testing purposes. Sometimes the current 15s timeout is not enough to get a location fix...
        //mMainHandler.postDelayed(mExpiredRunnable, LOCATION_REQUEST_UPDATE_TIMEOUT);

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

    @DebugLog
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mMainHandler.removeCallbacks(mExpiredRunnable);

        handleNewOrEmptyLocation(location);
    }

    @DebugLog
    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        // TODO: Is there something that needs to be done here?
        Timber.e("onConnectionSuspended");
    }

    @DebugLog
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        // TODO: Is there something that needs to be done here?
        Timber.e("onConnectionFailed");
    }

    @DebugLog
    private void handleNewOrEmptyLocation(Location location) {
        MyApplication.getInstance().unregisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);

        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();

        if (location != null) {
            mLocationCallback.onLocationReceived(location);
        } else {
            mLocationCallback.onEmptyLocation();
        }
    }

    public interface LocationCallback {

        void onLocationReceived(Location location);

        void onEmptyLocation();

    }

}
```

And this is how it's currently being used:

```
public class MAinActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation(this);

        myLocation.requestFusedLocation(new MyLocation.LocationCallback() {

            @DebugLog
            @Override
            public void onLocationReceived(Location location) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(location), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @DebugLog
            @Override
            public void onEmptyLocation() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "HUSTON, WE HAVE A PROBLEM!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }

        });
    }

}
```

To finish and as bonus question... In what circumstances are `onConnectionSuspended` and `onConnectionFailed` called? Should I handle these callbacks somehow?